# How to scope Rails model id which is dependent on belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have next structure of models in my app:

```
class Company
  has_many :employees
end

class Employee
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Is there a way to make it possible for employees to have unique ids (default primary keys) depending on `belongs_to` Company association?

These should return different Employee models:

`/companies/1/employees/1`

`/companies/2/employees/1`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the [sequenced](https://github.com/djreimer/sequenced) gem, it does exactly what you're asking. There is one consideration to keep in mind though.

Your requirement deprives `Employee`'s `id` field of uniqueness which it needs to be a primary key. Therefore you'd either need to have a composite key in `Employee`, namely `[:company_id, :employee_id]` or use the `Employee`'s `acts_as_sequenced` field not as the primary key but more like a slug.

Just in case you care to explore the composite key approach, there is [composite_primary_key](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) gem which aims to support ActiveRecord associations on top of composite keys. I haven't tried it myself though.

According to its docs, your associations could look something like this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees, :foreign_key => [:company_id, :employee_id]
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = :user_id, :employee_id
  belongs_to :company
end
```

But its quite likely this is an overkill approach for your goal.